# Would a 20A, 12v fuse be functionally identical to a 1A, 240v fuse?

Tags: voltage, amperage, fuses, watts

1Ax240V=240W

20Ax12V=240W

Assuming both fuses are of the same type, would they be interchangeable?
I'm aware that 240v fuses may not exist. I'm assessing the viability of substituting a 250v fuse with a 12v fuse.

Comment: No... and most often you wont find fuses that are only 12v. All those blade car fuses are like 36v and the glass ones tend to be 240v. The amperage needs to match your intended application.

Comment: The voltage rating in fuses indicates the minimum guaranteed isolation voltage when they are blown. For a non-blown fuse, there is very little voltage difference between its ends.

Answer (score 8):

A fuse only knows the current flowing through it - it does not know what the circuit voltage is until it blows.

A fuse will blow (or a circuit breaker will trip) based on the current flowing through it.  If the voltage across the fuse after it blows is higher than the fuse voltage rating, the fuse may arc or otherwise not blow cleanly.

Answer (score 4):

Of course they are not interchangeable.

The other one blows at 1A and the other one blows at 20A.

The other one is rated to safely handle 12V while the other is rated to safely handle 240V.

They are not interchangeable in any way and it would be extremely dangerous to put a 12V fuse where 250V is required, or to put a 20A fuse where 1A is required.

Answer (score 4):

No, the ratings are unrelated.

### Only current matters to a non-blown fuse.

A fuse that is not blown has zero volts across it.

Go look up in the sky at power lines.  Follow them a bit and you'll find a lumpy thing that is a fuse.  It has 9600V (compared to ground) on one side, and 9600V (compared to ground) on the other side.  Same voltage.   If we shift our frame of perspective to one of the wires, now we are at 0V, the ground is at 9600V, *and the wire on the other side of the fuse is at 0V*.   There is functionally 0V across the fuse*.  Get it?  The fuse doesn't know from voltage.

So the only thing the fuse cares about is how much current goes through it.  It really would not know if the voltage *to the ground* is 9.6 volts or 9600 volts. It's not on the ground, and it doesn't have any role in insulating the wires from the ground.

The power line fuse would work fine on a 9.6 volt circuit.

However, when the fuse blows, the current wants to keep going and the fuse's job is to stop it.

### Only voltage matters to a blown fuse.

A blown fuse isn't supposed to handle any current.

So what matters is the voltage on both sides of the fuse.  On the load side, the voltage has dropped to the voltage of the other phase(s) or neutral.   That voltage difference is trying to leap across the fuse, and the fuse's job is to prevent that.

So now, finally, this is when the fuse's voltage rating comes into play.  The fuse up on the power line is designed and rated to stop 9600 volts.  An automotive fuse wouldn't do the job there, the 9600 volts would just leap across the little gap.

So now you understand the puzzle.  A 1 amp in a 12 volt context would only allow 1 amp through, or 12 watts.  In a 20A circuit it would just blow immediately.

But a 12V fuse in a 240V context would work fine until it blows for some reason.  Then, the 240V voltage difference would laugh at the fuse and leap right across it.

---

*  Not quite 0V as there is some tiny amount of resistance - that is needed to create the heat that would burn out the fuse if it is overloaded.

Comment: A high voltage fuse may have a somewhat higher resistance than its lower voltage equivalent. So a 9600 volt 1 amp fuse on a 12V circuit may drop as much as 1 volt (hardly noticeable on 9600V), but nearly 10% loss on a 12V circuit.

Comment: @PStechPaul True. Edited.